# New dijit.form.Button keeps autoclicking upon declaration

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm trying to programmatically insert a dijit.form.Button into some HTML and my code goes like this:

```
row.innerHTML = '<td>Name:</td><td id="showname" />';
var showButton = new dijit.form.Button({
    label: "Show name",
    style: "float: right",
    onClick: show_name(),
}, "showname")
```

But every time I refresh and update the page, it will automatically run show_name(), which is not what I want. Can anyone give me some insight as to why this is happening, and how I can fix it so that show_name() is only run when the button is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: Try just `show_name`, or `function() { show_name(); }` Javascript works in mysterious ways.

Comment: post this as an answer, it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just `show_name`, or `function() { show_name(); }`.

My explanation is that you need a function reference, not a function call, which passes back the return value (probably nothing) back to `onClick`. The first option works when no arguments are passed, in the second option you can pass anything into `show_name()`.

Comment: yeah, either of those options worked. turns out JS was treating it like a function call and not a parameter definition. thanks a lot!